# Bogoliubov-de Gennes equation and how to diagonalize

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, computational-physics, simulations, bose-einstein-condensate

Can someone please share how you would go on to solve the Bogoliubov-de Gennes equation for a Bose-Einstein condensate with a potential. In particular, how would you deal with the diagonalization when an operator (Laplacian in the Hamiltonian) is included? I would like to know the eigenvalues $\omega_i$ for the case of a trapped Bose gas (1D is ok, and for simplicty a step potential can be taken).

[image]

Comment: Or can I use a Fourier transform? But here there is NO translational invariance

Comment: As an extra, maybe one could provide a basic pseudocode for solving this.

Comment: Related question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71226231/numerical-diagonalization-of-hamiltonian-using-matlab

Comment: If you are dealing with a solid, oftentimes there is discrete translational invariance of the potential (e.g., translations along the crystal lattice vectors). If you are dealing with "jellium" then there is translational invariance.

Comment: pseudocode for numerical solution of the Laplace equation or what?

Comment: I am dealing with a Bose-Einstein condensate with a position-varying step potential

Comment: @hft: so there is no translational invariance, because in that case I could have chosen a plane wave

Comment: Find eigenstates of the potential and use those eigenstates as a new basis to rewrite the Hamiltonian.

Comment: So for the potential step, what do you suggest? And I would like to know how to diagonalize this Hamiltonian (not another one)

Comment: I know $\psi$ and all those things.... Only question is how to diagonalize since an operator (the Laplacian) is involved

Comment: @MrQ Could you give a link or upload equations you are asking for?

Comment: @AlexTrounev: I am asking on how to numerically solve the Bogoliubov-de Gennes equations in Pitaevskii-Stringari book (5.68) or Pethik-Smith book on bose-einstein condensates